# Subject observable on a service not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've got a component A, which sends a value to a service method (via calling it), and then I tried to create a subject and 'observe' it from component B, thus triggering an action on component B from component A. 
This is what I did:

***Component A sends the data:***

```
this.service.method(id_estado)
```

***Which is recieved by service:***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, of, Observable, Subscription, Subject  }    from 'rxjs';
export class service {
    estado: any;
    subject = new Subject<any>();
    constructor( private api: ApiService ) {
    } 
    service ( id_estado ){
        let subject = new Subject<any>();
        this.subject.next(estado)
    }
}
```

***And in component B I'm trying to observe it like this:***

```
this.service.subject.subscribe( (data) => {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Component B's part takes place inside a method. Is this the cause of the problem? I can't get any data to show on my console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Component B's part takes place inside a method. Is this the cause of
>   the problem?

Yes, that's the problem. If that method isn't called, then you aren't subscribing to the `Subject` and that is why no data is received.

Move this subscribing part to `ngOnInit` of Component B.

Also in the service, you are creating a new `Subject` whenever that method is called.
`Subject` is already defined at the beginning, no need to do it again.

After this change, your service should look like:

```
export class service {
    estado: any;
    subject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor( private api: ApiService ) {
    } 

    service(id_estado) {
      this.subject.next(estado);
    }
}
```

Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-components-communication-using-subject) where you can see components communicating in real time using `Subject`.

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
let subject = new Subject<any>();
this.subject.next(estado)
```

-  should be moved to constructor to be initialized.

or just execute service in constructor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, of, Observable, Subscription, Subject  }    from 'rxjs';
export class service {
    estado: any;
    subject = new Subject<any>();
    constructor( private api: ApiService ) {
        service(true); // or some value you need.
    } 
    service (id_estado){
        this.subject.next(estado);
    }
}
```

In this case you can remove initialization  `subject = new Subject<any>();` before constructor.

In your case you've just got `Subject`, but `.next()` wasn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

you should try event emitter service of angular, in which you subscribe your data in pass that data value in any component using event emitter service.

Comment: I honestly tried to read on the syntax but I was not able to even sketch something useful. I guess I will have to try that way because I cant seem to make it work.
EDIT: this are also sibling components, does that work in that case? I tought @ input and @ output where exclusively for parent-child data transfers